# How do I override the default session timeout with pyramid + pyramid-beaker + beaker

Tags: python, pyramid, beaker

I am using pyramid to create a web application. I am then using pyramid-beaker to interface beaker into pyramid's session management system.

Two values affect the duration of a user's session.

1. The session cookie timeout
2. The actual session's life time on either disk/memcache/rdbms/etc

I currently have to cookie defaulted (via the standard beaker config) to delete when the browser closes. I have the session data set to clear out after 2 hours. This works prefectly.

What I need to know is how to override the cookie's timeout and the session timeout to both be 30 days or some other arbirtrary value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the timeout isn't supported by beaker. If you are trying to make a session stick around that long, you should probably just put it into a separate cookie. A common use-case is the "remember me" checkbox on login. This helps you track who the user is, but generally the actual session shouldn't be sticking around that long and gets recreated.

Comment: Then why does Beaker take a timeout parameter? http://readthedocs.org/docs/beaker/en/v.1.6.1/modules/session.html

Comment: Beaker handles creating cookies for you on first access to the SessionObject proxy in Pyramid. This makes the constructor parameters not configurable on a per-request basis with dissecting the internals of the SessionObject so that you can inject a manually created session into it or circumventing the SessionObject entirely.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. So strictly, your first sentence of your original reply isn't true, only in this context? Thanks :) (It does work for me in Pylons, though.)

Comment: It'll work if you're manually creating `Session` or `CookieSession` objects yourself, but then you're responsible for ensuring things are persisted in your response object. Pretty sure if you're using the SessionMiddleware in Pylons you have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have a [solution](https://github.com/enomado/beaker/commit/87151c0c6dfcc080fa80dc1b3dc9056c976c6ae1). Its old but works.